# How to build different projects requiring different webpack versions?

Tags: webpack

I have a new installation of ubuntu 18.04 with apache installed on it.

I've had to download several ReactJS projects developed by other colleagues/freelancers.  It seems every project requires that I build it with `webpack` command.  However, each project requires a different version of `webpack`.

After much struggling, I was able to get one of my projects to build when using webpack 3.10.0.  This is the version that is installed globally on my ubuntu.

So my question is how do people generally go about building different ReactJS projects on the same machine while requiring different versions of webpack?  Do I need to uninstall and reinstall webpack with the version I'd like to build with?

---

NOTE TO SELF

To build project 1, I do this:

```
sudo npm uninstall -g webpack
sudo npm install -g webpack@3.10.0
webpack
```

Then to build project 2, I do this:

```
sudo npm uninstall -g webpack
sudo npm install -g webpack@2.1.0
webpack
```

etc...

Comment: why not specify the version in your packagejson and install the webpack cli?

Comment: ok i'll have to research that to understand better how web pack actually works. Some package.json in some projects seem to have the webpack version mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible!

However, it requires you to bypass Webpack's cli commands within package.json for a shared node script instead.

**1)** You need to be running the latest version of NPM to utilize it's newer package npm:XXX@XXX alias feature:

*Package.json devDependencies:*

```
"devDependencies": {
  "webpack-cli": "^3.3.8",
  "webpack4.39.3": "npm:webpack@4.39.3",
  "webpack4.39.2": "npm:webpack@4.39.2"
}
```

Now you should have two versions of Webpack installed:

- node_modules/webpack4.39.3/
- node_modules/webpack4.39.2/

**I suggest you delete node_modules and reinstall with dual Webpack version alias so no lingering /node_modules/webpack/ folder is found.**

**2)** Next, update package.json scripts to bypass Webpack commands, and instead run a shared config node script. This is cause Webpack does not allow for a way to alias internal CLI command yet.

*Package.json scripts:*

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "npm run newer && npm run older",
  "newer": "node ./wp.config.js webpack@4.39.3",
  "older": "node ./wp.config.js webpack@4.39.2"
}
```

**3)** Now in the wp.config.js Node script we simply:

- Import all versions of Webpack we need
- Make config object that can be shared across both Webpack versions
- Condition for which version we want to use off process.argv
- Run wanted Webpack version's method directly with config object

*wp.config.js shared configuration file*

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack4_39_3 = require('./node_modules/webpack4.39.3/lib/webpack.js');
const webpack4_39_2 = require('./node_modules/webpack4.39.2/lib/webpack.js');
let webpack;

// make a shared configuration for webpack
const config = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist')
  },
  mode: 'production',
  module: {
    rules: []
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: false
  },
  plugins: []
};

// condition for which webpack version to use
// bonus, setting config object's 'output.filename' based on condition
if (process.argv.indexOf('webpack@4.39.3') !== -1) {
  webpack = webpack4_39_3;
  config.output.filename = './main@4.39.3.js';
}

if (process.argv.indexOf('webpack@4.39.2') !== -1) {
  webpack = webpack4_39_2;
  config.output.filename = './main@4.39.2.js';
}

// Run webpack from node
webpack(config, (err, stats) => { // Stats Object
  if (err || stats.hasErrors()) {
    // Handle errors here
  }
  // Done processing
});
```

Works over shared or unique sources / configurations, that can all be conditioned at multiple levels.